# Excel: Find number of records matching multiple criteria AND using time since the first record was created

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am looking for some help with a formula. On my 'data' sheet, I have data in the format below:

```
   A         B            C            D            E          F        G           H           I          J
1 UID   RecordType      HCode     AdmittedDate   Forename   Surname    ReviewDate     Sex        STDate      RDate
2 87962 STAsses         STIV1     01/07/2012     Mark       Jones                     Male   09/12/2012 
3 89658 Transfer        GLSI2     01/01/2012     Alison     Aitken                    Female                 08/07/2013 
4 87962 Discharge       STIV1                    Mark       Jones      20/07/2012     Male               08/07/2013
5 89654 STAsses         STGE1     01/01/2012     Andrew     Macbeth                   Male   08/07/2012  
6 89867 Transfer        KIND1     01/01/2012     George     Deas                      Male               08/07/2013 
7 87962 Transfer        STIV1                    Mark       Jones      14/07/2012     Male               04/03/2013 
8 89654 Transfer        STGE1     01/01/2012     Andrew     Macbeth                   Male               12/08/2012
```

On my 'report' sheet, I have the following table set up:

```
      B             C             D            E            F
4 HospCode     RecordType     0-2 Weeks    2-4 Weeks    4-6 Weeks
5 STIV1        Transfers
6              Discharges
7              
8
```

On my 'report' sheet, I'm looking to count the number of the number of 'transfers' and 'discharges' (as specified in column b of the 'data' sheet) occurring within the time frames in columns D, E, F etc.

In summary, what I'm looking for in cell D5 is to count the number of 'transfers' (as specified in column b of 'data' sheet) for hospcode 'STIV1', occurring within 0-2 weeks of the corresponding 'STAsses' record (which is also specified in column b). D6 would be the same, only the number of 'discharge' records occurring within the specified time frame.

I don't know where to start with this, or if it's possible to do. Each person will have at least have an STAsses record but not always a 'Transfer' or 'Discharge' record. The 'UID' is the same for each person, so this could be used to match 'STAsses' entries with 'Transfer' and 'Discharge' entries.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: If this is real personal data, Such as hospital records are you sure you want to be posting them freely on public forums? I would blank out the data fields such as ID numbers and Names of people.

Comment: Nathan, this is dummy data purely to give as much information as possible to help resolve my query.

Comment: ah I see no problem just thought I'd make sure can never be too safe with info like that :)

Comment: `COUNTIF` is the excel function you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks Tyson. I know about COUNTIF and can use that to count the multiple conditions, but not to match this against the previous STAsses record.

Comment: Your question doesn't mention needing to use STAsses records.  As stated right now COUNTIFS would work fine.

Comment: The question doesn't mention needing to use STAsses records... except for the last two paragraphs. As stated right now, countifs would do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to go about this, but none of them are going to be simple. One way would be to make a combined date column so that would sum(stdate, rdate). It appears only one of those dates is filled at one time, so the sum would really just be combining them properly into a single column.

[image]

Then you could throw a pivot table on top putting UID in the rows, RecordType in the columns, and the new Combined Date column in the Values (as a SUM). Since Combined Date is distinct to the UID/RecordType combination, no actual dates will be summed here, so you'll just end up with a nice table of Distinct UIDs and their respective STAsses, Transfer, and Discharge dates on the same line.

[image]

With that information you can now subtract your STAsses date from your Transfer and Dischage date and divide by 7 to get the Weeks that elapsed between the two times. You can also perform a vlookup to bring in the HCode.

At the end of this new set of data you can make new columns to capture 0-2 discharge, 0-2 transfer, 2-4 discharge, 2-4 transfer, etc... You can use an if statement to fill these like `If(dischargeweeks<2, 1, 0)`, `If(transferweeks<2, 1, 0)`, etc..  (note that the data in the 0-2, 2-4 type columns is made up since your sample data spat out numbers in the hundreds of weeks range).

[image]

Now pivot this new data (I know... pivots pivots pivots)... This time stick hcode in the rows, and your 0-2 Discharge, 0-2 transfer, etc  in the values. It will now give you a count of each of these for each distinct HCode... which is REALLY close to what you want.

[image]

Lastly, I just copied and pasted (and you could sort afterwards) to get it in the right format... I mean, at this point whats a little copy and paste, right?

[image]

All that being said, you could work up a nice bit of VBA to just run through the list, calculate everything and spit out on a new sheet. I guess it just depends if this is a one time thing on a big piece of data, or if you will be doing this every day...

Lastly, since I can't see every strange thing that might be in your data, this is really only a set of suggestions. There may be bits here that just won't work or bits that might need to be changed slightly, but the jist is the same... Use pivots to summarize your data, do some more calculations, and pivot again... it's not pretty but it gets the job done.

Comment: Thank you so much for the effort you've put into this. I'll have a play with this tomorrow and feedback on how I get on, but right off the bat, this is looking great and could be a real workable solution. :)